# Connect to ssl server using java client

Tags: java, security, ssl-certificate

I am given a certificate by my api provider which are .crt file and .p12 file.

I generated ca-cert.pem file from .crt file and 
client-cert.pem and client-key.pem file from .p12 file using openssl as required by api.

I am also provided with username password for basic authentication by my api provider.

My question is how can I connect to server url https (rest) using these certificate and credentials using Java.

Answer (score 1):

You basically have to create an [SSLSocketFactory](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLSocketFactory.html) see here for an [example](http://ww.delphifaq.com/faq/f5003.shtml). Once you've created the SSLSocketFactory you can set it when you create a Connection from the URL like so.

```
SSLSocketFactory sf = ... see that example
URL url = new URL("https://google.com");
HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setSSLSocketFactory(sf);
... Now do stuff with that connection like GET or POST
```

Also fyi, you are going to want to convert your certificates into the JKS format that Java prefers in order to easily load them into the SSLSocketFactory. You can use a program called [keytool](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/keytool.html) that comes with java which can help you out.